# detailCalloutAccessoryView hides subtitle

Tags: swift, annotations

On iOS 9 when I add detailCalloutAccessoryView to my annotation, the subtitle disappears. Is this an SDK limitation or known problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the fact that detail callout accessory view replaces the subtitle is a known/intended behavior.

If you want a custom detail accessory view that also includes the `subtitle` of the annotation, you can just add your own `UILabel` as a subview of the view you add as the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` (and obviously set its `text`, too).